# event.dataTransfer loses its items inside setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout

Can someone please explain why this is happening. This is in the `ondrop` handler

Why does it loses it's values inside the timer?

```
var _this = this;

this.event = event;

console.log(this.event.dataTransfer.items);
## DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, length: 1, item: function, clear: function, add: function}


setTimeout((function() {
  return console.log(_this.event.dataTransfer.items);
  ## DataTransferItemList {length: 0, item: function, clear: function, add: function}

}), 100);
```

Even this does not work:

```
var items, _items,
  _this = this;

items = event.dataTransfer.items;
_items = items;

setTimeout((function() {
  return console.log(_items);
}), 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading [HTML5 Drag and drop](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html) correctly the `dataTransfer` object is associated with the "drag data store" only for the duration of drag and drop, other times it is disassociated or disabled which in practical terms means the `items` is empty.

So, `event.dataTransfer` is usable only from within the `ondrop` handler, if you need the retain the items beyond that you'll need to copy them (although I'm not sure copying the items would work as expected, you may need to extract the data you need straight away.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. This is all happening inside the ondrop handeler like you said. The timeout function is inside the handeler.

Comment: I meant in terms of execution time. The `ondrop` handler is called, and as soon as the handler function returns the `event.dataTransfer` is probably reset.

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem seams to be that the `this` that is calling your function will not be the same `this` when the setTimeout timer runs, which will be `window` so therefore you need to change it if you want the correct behaviour:

Taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) override the setTimeout and setInterval globally with this overrides:

```
// Just place this lines in your javascript file
// Enable the passage of the 'this' object through the JavaScript timers
var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout, __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;
window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};

window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};
```

Then your function will work as expected:

```
...
console.log(this.event.dataTransfer);
## DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, length: 1, item: function, clear: function, add: function}

setTimeout((function() {
  return console.log(this.event.dataTransfer);
  ## DataTransferItemList {length: 0, item: function, clear: function, add: function}
}), 100);
...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: edited my answer to retain the items directly, still same result?

Comment: Is it not perhaps because the event is unbinded after is binded or something?